# Escaping freeform text in github actions to safely populate shell variables

Tags: bash, github-actions

I have a GitHub Action that adds a prefix to the PR's title if its branch name has a specific prefix. It throws an error (or otherwise misbehaves) if `github.event.pull_request.title` contains unescaped characters like backticks, `$`s, quotes (of the same kind that surround the substitution point), etc.

How can I safely substitute GitHub Action variables into my script if I don't control their content?

```bash
title="${{ github.event.pull_request.title }}"

if [[ ${{ github.head_ref }} = hotfix/* ]] && [[ $title != hotfix:* ]]; then
  echo "Marking as hotfix."
  gh pr edit ${{ env.PR_NUMBER }} --title "hotfix: ${title}"
fi
```

Comment: Use single quotes, so the shell doesn't try to interpret the content? See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3001761

Comment: Then it will fail if the content contains a single quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, use a templating system that performs shell-safe escaping itself; it's a common feature.

Unfortunately, the docs for GitHub actions don't indicate that it supports that (very common) feature -- but it *does* support JSON, so you can use that:

```
read_nullsep() {
  local arg
  for arg; do
    IFS= read -r -d '' "$arg" || return
  done
}

read_nullsep title head_ref pr_number < <(jq -j '(tostring | gsub("\u0000"; ""), "\u0000")' <<'EOF'
${{ toJSON(github.event.pull_request.title) }}
${{ toJSON(github.head_ref) }}
${{ toJSON(env.PR_NUMBER) }}
EOF
) || { echo "Error decoding metadata" >&2; exit 1; }

if [[ $head_ref = hotfix/* ]] && [[ $title != hotfix:* ]]; then
  echo "Marking as hotfix."
  gh pr edit "$pr_number" --title "hotfix: ${title}"
fi
```

Some implementation notes:

- Using `jq -j` is an equivalent to `jq -r` that *doesn't* add an automatic newline between items, allowing the user to add a delimiter themselves instead; in this case, the delimiter we're adding is `"\u0000"`, a NUL.
- Using `gsub("\u0000", "")` tells jq to discard any NULs in the JSON content, such that the only NULs present in the output can be the ones we explicitly added as delimiters.
- Using `read -r` tells `read` to treat backslashes as literal data.
- Using `read -d ''` tells `read` to continue until it encounters end-of-file or a NUL literal.
- You could *probably* just use `"$PR_NUMBER"` directly in your shell script and avoid templating it out at all, assuming that it's passed through as an environment variable.

Comment: Thanks. I only need to do this for the title; the rest isn't causing issues.

Comment: I wear a security hat, so I worry about _anything_ an attacker impersonating one of your developers could conceivably control. Better to be paranoid than to be the next Solar Winds.

Comment: That's a fair point :)